# Fragment animation shortened by view inflating

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-animation

I have an `Activity` that holds a bunch of fragments. Each fragment transitions to the next one with a sliding animation.

Here's how it's built:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

So every `Fragment` (nextFragment) is pushed onto the `fragment_container` with:

```
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(R.animator.enter_from_left, R.animator.exit_to_right, R.animator.enter_from_right, R.animator.exit_to_left)
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, nextFragment);
                .addToBackStack(nextFragment.getFragmentTAG());
                .commit();
```

Pretty simple so far. There is no issue pushing and popping onto/from the back stack.

### Issue

My issue comes from the fact that some fragments contain a list, and these lists are populated dynamically in the `onCreateView()` method with `ListCell` views. So if I have 6 `ListCell`s in my Fragment to display, I do inflate 6 ListCell views, which takes about 45-50ms each.
Knowing that the Fragment animation takes 500ms, about half of it is lost inflating those views, which in the end, gives a ~250ms animation or less.

Currently, I have a `LinearLayout` inside of a `ScrollView`:

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/list_container"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</ScrollView>
```

### Question

Is there a way for me to either thread that processing, or pre-inflate those views in order to keep the animation in full ?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you want to waste your user's time with extra waiting. I would redesign to somehow blend the animation of the list filling, with the animation of the fragment change. Will need some designing.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a thread that cause a delay before inflating the list item of 500ms. In this time transition animations will be finished. Now your can start inflating the list items. 
Just wrap you listview inflating code in a method and call it here:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           //inflate the list items here      
        }
    },500);
```